# VB ComboBox Requires 2 Mouse Clicks to Select Index?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

For some reason with this combobox I have in my code, when I run the program, it does not change the Selected Index with one mouse click. Instead, I have to select the drop down of the combo box again, and then select the index. Any ideas on what is going on here? Here is my code, I've tinkered with it for hours.

```
Public Class Form1
    'Mod-level variable
    Dim TransactionList As New List(Of Transaction)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.Text = "Mike Smith's Bank Account"
        Lb1.Visible = False
        Lb2.Visible = False
        Lb4.Visible = False
        Tb1.Visible = False
        Tb2.Visible = False
        SubmitTransactionButton.Visible = False
        TransactionListBox.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Cb1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If Tb1.Text = "" Then
            Tb1.Text = "0.00"

        ElseIf Cb1.Text = "" Then
            Lb4.Visible = False
            LbAction.Visible = False
            Lb1.Visible = False
            Lb2.Visible = False
            Tb1.Visible = False
            Tb2.Visible = False
            TransactionListBox.Visible = False
            SubmitTransactionButton.Visible = False

        ElseIf Cb1.Text = "Credit" Then
            Lb4.Visible = False
            LbAction.Visible = False
            Lb1.Visible = True
            Lb2.Visible = True
            LbAction.Visible = False
            Tb1.Visible = True
            Tb2.Visible = True
            TransactionListBox.Visible = False
            Lb1.Text = "Enter Credit Amount"
            Lb2.Text = "Describe the Income"
            SubmitTransactionButton.Visible = True

        ElseIf Cb1.Text = "Debit" Then
            LbAction.Visible = False
            Lb1.Visible = True
            Lb4.Visible = False
            Lb2.Visible = True
            LbAction.Visible = False
            Tb1.Visible = True
            Tb2.Visible = True
            TransactionListBox.Visible = False
            Lb1.Text = "Enter Debit Amount"
            Lb2.Text = "Describe the Expense"
            SubmitTransactionButton.Visible = True

        ElseIf Cb1.Text = "Display Transactions" Then
            TransactionListBox.Visible = True
            Lb4.Visible = False
            LbAction.Visible = False
            Lb1.Visible = False
            Lb2.Visible = False
            Tb1.Visible = False
            Tb2.Visible = False
            SubmitTransactionButton.Visible = False


            For Each transaction In TransactionList
                TransactionListBox.Items.Add(
                  String.Format("{0}: {1:C}. {2}",
                                transaction.Type,
                                transaction.Amount,
                                transaction.Description))
            Next

        ElseIf Cb1.Text = "Display Balance" Then
            Lb4.Visible = True
            Lb1.Visible = False
            Lb2.Visible = False
            LbAction.Visible = False
            Tb1.Visible = False
            Tb2.Visible = False
            TransactionListBox.Visible = False
            Lb4.Text = "Current Balance: $"


        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub SubmitTransactionButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitTransactionButton.Click
        Dim transactionTypeString As String = Cb1.Text
        Dim transactionDescriptionstring As String = Tb2.Text
        Dim transactionAmountDecimal As Decimal

        If Tb1.Text IsNot "" Then
            'Tb1.Text = "0.00"
            Tb2.Text = ""
            Cb1.Text = ""
            Lb1.Visible = False
            Lb2.Visible = False
            Tb1.Visible = False
            Tb2.Visible = False
            SubmitTransactionButton.Visible = False
        End If

        Try
            transactionAmountDecimal = Decimal.Parse(Tb1.Text)
            TransactionList.Add(New Transaction(
                              transactionTypeString,
                              transactionAmountDecimal,
                              transactionDescriptionstring))

        Catch FormatExceptionParameter As FormatException
            transactionAmountDecimal = 0D

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class Transaction
    Public Sub New(type As String, amount As Decimal, description As String)
        Me.Type = type
        Me.Amount = amount
        Me.Description = description

        If Me.Type = "Credit" Then
            Me.Amount *= -1
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Property Type As String
    Public Property Amount As Decimal
    Public Property Description As String
End Class
```

Comment: also this program is incomplete, but this is just an issue that has been bothering me for some time now.

Comment: Have you had a look at the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Does it only do this on the first attempt to change index after every new run, or does every single attempt to change the index require a second click? What is `tb1` and what is its initial value?

Comment: It only does this on first attempt to change index after every new run, yes. tb1 is text box 1 and it's initial value is "'